# How can i do this type of design using html, css

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqKA5.jpg)

How can I do this type of design. Will this be in a new separate section or in that section where other tags attributes are present.
I have no idea how to do this and also responsive in proper way. Or any specific library needed to do this.

Comment: if you want to use "html and css", then `javascript` and `jquery` are pointless tags. As for responsive, it really depends on how you want the page to look at different break points

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use svg (with 100% width). You can e.g. generate random wave from this site: https://getwaves.io/

```html
<div style="background:#FF0057"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,64L13.3,96C26.7,128,53,192,80,224C106.7,256,133,256,160,261.3C186.7,267,213,277,240,245.3C266.7,213,293,139,320,112C346.7,85,373,107,400,117.3C426.7,128,453,128,480,144C506.7,160,533,192,560,186.7C586.7,181,613,139,640,149.3C666.7,160,693,224,720,229.3C746.7,235,773,181,800,144C826.7,107,853,85,880,64C906.7,43,933,21,960,48C986.7,75,1013,149,1040,176C1066.7,203,1093,181,1120,149.3C1146.7,117,1173,75,1200,53.3C1226.7,32,1253,32,1280,69.3C1306.7,107,1333,181,1360,224C1386.7,267,1413,277,1427,282.7L1440,288L1440,320L1426.7,320C1413.3,320,1387,320,1360,320C1333.3,320,1307,320,1280,320C1253.3,320,1227,320,1200,320C1173.3,320,1147,320,1120,320C1093.3,320,1067,320,1040,320C1013.3,320,987,320,960,320C933.3,320,907,320,880,320C853.3,320,827,320,800,320C773.3,320,747,320,720,320C693.3,320,667,320,640,320C613.3,320,587,320,560,320C533.3,320,507,320,480,320C453.3,320,427,320,400,320C373.3,320,347,320,320,320C293.3,320,267,320,240,320C213.3,320,187,320,160,320C133.3,320,107,320,80,320C53.3,320,27,320,13,320L0,320Z"></path></svg></div>
```